# Looping through an mysql array and printing each row into a <select>

Tags: php, html, mysql

I want to retrieve each row from one column in one table and put all of them in a  element.
I'm pretty much flailing in the dark right now, what am I doing wrong/missing?

```
$db_connect = mysql_connect("$host", "$db_username", "$db_password");
$db_select = mysql_select_db("$db_name");
mysql_set_charset('utf8', $db_connect);

$db_query_project="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name";

print('<form name="report" method="post" action="">');
print('<label for="project">Projekt </label>');
print('<select name="project_select">');

print('<option>Test</option>');

foreach ($db_query_project as $key => $value){
        print('<option>'.$key['project_name'].'</option>');
}
print('</select>');
print('</form>');
```

Is there a better way to go about doing this?

Comment: You're missing the part where you execute the query?

Comment: I am? I'm quite new to php and mysql, how would i execute it?

Comment: _Insert obligatory "use non-deprecated [mysqli](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) instead of [mysql](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysql.php)" comment here_

Comment: @jterry Yes I know, I thought I would get the basics working using mysql since I'm somewhat familiar with it and "port" it later.

Answer (score 1):

You need to connect to the database and perform the query in order to retrieve the data and fetch it. To do so, you can use either [mysqli](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php). Here's an example on how to fetch data from a table `$tbl_name` with a column `project_name` using mysqli.

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "user", "password", "database");
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ")";
exit();
}

$query = "SELECT * FROM `$tbl_name`";

if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {

    /* fetch associative array */
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        printf ("%s \n", $row["project_name"]);
    }

    /* free result set */
    $result->free();
}

/* close connection */
$mysqli->close();
```

Comment: My apologies, I actually forgot to paste the part where I make the connection. I copied your code and entered host, user etc but I'm getting nothing.

Comment: Please check the PHP error log and report back any error you get. In your original code you're still not fetching the data and executing the query. Does your table have a "project_name" column? Are the variables $db_name, $host, $db_password declared elsewhere in your code?

Comment: I've noticed an unclosed parenthesis in my code - please try again and report back. This error, btw, should appear in your PHP error console: you should really look forward to find the location of the PHP log files to check errors when you write code.

Comment: I noticed that missing parenthesis, still didn't work.
Table does have a column named project_name and the variables are declared at the very top of the same document I'm working in.
Where do I find the error log?
The database is on a shared host, so I'm not working against a localhost.

Comment: It depends on your php.ini configuration, I have no idea on how your server works. If you can't locate the error log, try to call var_dump($mysqli) in various line and see if the error property shows some code. Still, findind the PHP console log would be bettere.

Comment: Also, is $tbl_name specified in your code and is it the same as the effective table in your database? Perhaps you need backticks in the query: I've added them. Hole this will fix the problem, even I doubt so.

Answer (score 0):

i prefer this one:

```
function getFieldSelect($name, $selected, $values, $attributes) {
    $r = "<select name=\"$name\" $attributes>";
    foreach ($values as $k => $v) {
        if ($k == $selected) {
            $sel = "selected";
        } else {
            $sel = "";
        }
        $r .= "<option  value=\"$k\" $sel>$v</option>\n";
    }
    $r .= "</select>";
    return $r;
}
```

i got the values from DB and give it to my function in array format. I think this is the most flexible way to print a select field. You can use a database to get the values or any array.

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
$db_query_project= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $tbl_name");

echo '<form name="report" method="post" action="">';
echo '<label for="project">Projekt </label>';
echo '<select name="project_select">';

echo '<option>Test</option>';

while( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $db_query_project ) )
{
        echo '<option>'.$row['project_name'].'</option>';
}
echo '</select>';
echo '</form>';
```